# Prove that $\sum\frac{1}{|z_n|^2}=\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Consider $\{-int+m\in \Bbb{C}:n,m\in \Bbb{Z}\;\&\;n\geq1\}$, where $t>0$ is a fixed real number. Suppose
>    $\{z_n\}$ is a numeration of that set. Prove that
>    $\sum\dfrac{1}{|z_n|^2}=\infty$

What test can I use? It is a sequence with two variables $n,m$, how can I use something like ratio test or root test? Please give me some hints, thank you!

Comment: Does $int$ stand for $i\cdot n\cdot t$? If yes, then what is $t$? If no, then what is $int$?

Comment: I assume $t$ is a fixed real number. What can you say about the sum of those $1/|z|^2$ for which $|n| + |m| = c$ for fixed integer $c$?

Comment: @arkeet
Sorry for lack of information. Yes $t$ is a fixed real number $>0$.
If $|n|+|m|=c$ for fixed integer $c$, then I have $1/(|n|^2+|m|^2) \geq \frac{1}{c^2}$. Since we have infinitely many such pairs of $n$, $m$, so for $t=1$ the series diverges. 
For any $t>0$, I can also have such $c$ if $c$ is large enough.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There are $8k$ pairs $(m,n)$ with $\max(|m|,|n|)=k$.